# PYTHON: reading .jl file using jsonlines is resulting in line of json. I need all the json lines

Tags: python, json, jsonlines

I am trying to read the file from the path and add to the dictionary, however, i end up with first json-line and there are about 230MB of data.

I have folder like here

```
# folder path 
folder = os.path.expanduser("~/topic_2022-05-30T23-15-20.jl")

#Initialise the dictionary    
items = {}
with open(folder, 'rb') as f:
for item in json_lines.reader(f):
        
    # adding next item to items
    items.update(item)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
file = open(folder)
items = {}
data = json.load(file)
for k, v in data.items():
    items.update(k:v) 
 
file.close()
```

`itmes = data` could also work.